# How to configure runCxConsole.cmd file

Tags: command-line-interface, checkmarx

I am trying to use the Checkmarx CLI and there are some parameters that I really don't know how to configure.

This is the file:

```
@echo off

pushd "%~dp0"
set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_51
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
set CPATH=.;../config/cx_console.properties;


java -Xmx1024m -cp %CPATH% -jar CxConsolePlugin-CLI-7.5.0-20160719-1414.jar %*

popd
```

I really have no idea of what does it mean with pushd, popd and CPATH.
When I run the ant command I receive this:

```
CxScan:
     [echo] Initiating Checkmarx Scan
     [exec] /root/CxConsolePlugin-7.5.0-20160719-1414/runCxConsole.cmd: 3: /root/CxConsolePlugin-7.5.0-20160719-1414/runCxConsole.cmd: pushd: not found
     [exec] /root/CxConsolePlugin-7.5.0-20160719-1414/runCxConsole.cmd: 5: /root/CxConsolePlugin-7.5.0-20160719-1414/runCxConsole.cmd: %PATH%: not found
     [exec] /root/CxConsolePlugin-7.5.0-20160719-1414/runCxConsole.cmd: 6: /root/CxConsolePlugin-7.5.0-20160719-1414/runCxConsole.cmd: ../config/cx_console.properties: not found
     [exec] Error: Unable to access jarfile CxConsolePlugin-CLI-7.5.0-20160719-1414.jar
     [exec] /root/CxConsolePlugin-7.5.0-20160719-1414/runCxConsole.cmd: 11: /root/CxConsolePlugin-7.5.0-20160719-1414/runCxConsole.cmd: popd: not found
     [exec] Result: 127
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deal with pushd or anything:

Just look thru the CLI docs at https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/KC/CxConsole:+CxSAST+CLI

download the zip file, unzip and set the path and java variables, and see how you can launch a scan on the page I mentioned.

Comment: Have you used it? Would you mind helping me a little bit?

Comment: of course. I use it all the time.

first of all, pls confirm the following:

- cxSAST version

Comment: cxsast version, cli version, cli environment (windows, or unix)

Comment: Is there another way to contact you? I think I might neet a lot of help on this :(

Comment: I don't know how to do this. you can just answer my questions and we will go from there.

Comment: unix? oh that's why... you are running a cmd file on unix. you should run the other one (the sh file).

try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I am running the sh file but now I'm receiving this error:
` Caused by:` `org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.`
`         at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>`(WSDLServiceFactory.java:87)
`         at `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:218)
`         at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initialize(ServiceImpl.java:161)`
         ... 11 more`
`Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing`

Comment: ok - let's back up here: have you read the CLI docs and how to launch a scan? do you have access to the checkmarx application? as in, are you able to access the the checkmarx instance?

Comment: Yes, I can access to Checkmarx... the problem is that I'm using my windows' credentials. Do them change if I want to login from a linux machine?

Comment: you should be able to use cli and use windows credentials. I dont know how I can help you from here. it works for me with no issues. I suggest you contact checkmarx support... good luck